# Long TTFB with (relatively) small queries to SQL DB

Tags: php, sql, select, server-side

I've just spent two hours reading various articles on long TTFB and I'm just as confused as when I started. I think it's time to ask the experts.

In essence, I have a typical organizational hierarchical arrangement (CEO, VPs, Directors, Managers) drawing data from four (4) tables in a single DB. I use two Ajax queries: 1) creates the multidimensional array needed for a hierarchical tree and 2) using the first query, I then extract specific information pertaining to succession assignments.

My problem is long TTFB times. When I query at the lowest level (Manager without subordinates) the query returns in ~ 136ms. BUT, when I move three levels up to VP level (with subordinates), the TTFB is now over 8 seconds! I could understand this if there were lots of data to extract but the first query is only pulling 73 rows (9 cols) and the second query is pulling 98 rows (13 cols). This seems to be relatively small amounts of data for such a large TTFB.

Based on my reading, I am now wondering if I am creating a delay server-side as a result of poor coding for my two queries. Could someone comment on this and provide some direction? I would truly appreciate any input. Thank you. Here is my code:

**Query 1:**

```
function getSessionParent($userid)
    {
        return getSessionChilds('email_address = "' .$userid. '"');
    }
    
function getSessionChilds($criteria = '')
    {
        $criteria = " WHERE $criteria";
    
        global $dbc;
    
        $sql_query = "SELECT primes.prime_uid AS id, m.first_name, m.last_name, p.position_id, p.position_root, p.position_area, CONCAT(m.first_name, ' ', m.last_name, ' [', p.position_root, ']') AS value FROM positions p INNER JOIN master m ON p.jobholder_uid = m.email_address INNER JOIN primes ON m.email_address = primes.prime_uid $criteria ORDER BY m.last_name";
        $result_query = $dbc->query($sql_query);
    
        $org_levels = array();
        
        while ($org_level = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_query)){
            $session_id = $org_level['id'];
            $org_level['items'] = getSessionChilds('p.positionmgr_uid = "' .$session_id. '"');
                $org_levels[] = $org_level;
        }
    
        foreach ($org_levels as &$value) {
            $countChildren = count_arr_elements($value);
            if ($countChildren != 0) {
                $value['value'] = $value['value'] . " (".$countChildren.")";
            }
        }
    
        mysqli_free_result($result_query);
        unset($value);
        
        return $org_levels;
    }
```

**Query 2:**

```
function getSessionKP($response_orglevels)
{
    $prime_ids = [];
    $kp_positions = [];

    array_walk_recursive($response_orglevels, function($value,$key) use (&$prime_ids){
        if($key == 'id') $prime_ids[] = $value;
    });

    $prime_ids = array_map('json_encode', $prime_ids); // This is done to allow implode to work with proper quotations in array (SO #66163127)

    global $dbc;

    $sql_query = "SELECT w.kp_id AS id, w.user_id, w.key_position, w.area, w.criteria1, w.criteria2, w.criteria3, w.urgency, w.ro, w.span, m.last_name, CONCAT(m.first_name,' ',m.last_name) AS sponsor_name FROM worksheet_1_1b w INNER JOIN master m ON w.user_id = m.email_address WHERE user_id IN (" . implode(",", $prime_ids) . ")";
    $result_kp = $dbc->query($sql_query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_kp)) {
        $kp_positions[] = $row;
    }

    mysqli_free_result($result_kp);
    unset($value);

    return $kp_positions;
}
```

Comment: Two things come to mind inmediately: 1. Did you index your tables properly. 2. Find out where time is wasted. I'm not sure if that's any help to you...?

Comment: @KIKO Software 1. By "index" are you referring to setting up Primary Keys? I do not use Foreign Keys in my tables because they aren't needed. 2. Any suggestions on how to "find out" where the time is wasted? That's been my struggle. Thank you!!!

Comment: Indexes are more than just primary keys, you need to [choose the optimal indexes for your queries](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/guide-mysql-indexes). Finding where time is wasted means measuring time. Simply echoing a few [hrtime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hrtime.php) should tell a lot already. For example: `echo 'Before query: '; print_r(hrtime());`, followed by the same thing after the query. Etc.

Comment: @KIKO Software Wow! Did I come to the right place for help. I just indexed the first table and I'm already down from > 8 seconds to 300 ms! Granted, this table is a main feeder for the other tables but I had no idea how important indexing is. As I built my tables everything was responding so fast (with my demo data) I was lulled into not setting the tables up correctly in the first place. Truly appreciate the direction! Thank you.